# A way to increase the speed of cleaning DOM element content

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

there!
In my AJAX application I have a lot of content in the pages. So when the user changes the page, I have to clear the previous content in the page div. Using jQuery: cont.empty() or cont.html('') clears the DOM elements content and the associated data,events etc. But because of the big content, the performance of the page decreases dramatically. Sometimes it takes up to 500ms to clear the content on fast machine. I find out a way to clear the container super fast using pure JavaScript function:

```
function empty(element) {
    var i;
    for (i = element.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[i]);
}
```

This approach unfortunately generates memory leaks, because it doesn't clears the  associated elements jQuery data in the cache.

Can You give me an opinion or an approach that will clear the content quick and prevents memory leaks.

As example, is there a way to clear the content fast with the native function and at some point (interval function) to loop over $.cache and remove the stored missing handlers? Something like garbage collector.

Comment: Tried setting the parent element to display:none after that clearing the content and finish with setting display back?

Comment: var parent = cont.parent(); cont.remove(); parent.appendChild(newcont)

Comment: This is not helping. .empty(), .html('') and .remove() are equally slow. I already tried to hide/empty/show the container, but there was no change.

Comment: @n_ilievski: How comes it that you have such a lot of content to clear?

Comment: Well, jqgrid with 100 rows, row actions etc. is enough to notice that clearing the container is slow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filter when you define event handlers on elements in your container. For instance, you could use:

```
$(document).on("click", "#item1", function() {
    ...
});
```

instead of:

```
$("#item1").on("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan I think the idea is that since the event handlers aren't bound to the elements themselves there's no memory leak if you remove them without cleaning up the event handlers first.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist exactly

Comment: But there could be many other bindings resulting in leaks than the click event handler

Comment: @mplungjan Right. I don't agree with it, that just seemed to be the intention behind this. Data, plugins, and possibly event handlers from other scripts are all going to cause problems.

Comment: You are right if my application was small. But There are many plugin dependent controls in the pages, so It's impossible to rewrite everything in the application.

Comment: This is about event handlers. JQuery deals with those, but of course, you will have to deal with other sources of memory leaks on a case by case basis.